# Testing string for ascending order

Tags: java, random

I have written a piece of code here to generate a random PIN number of a specified length. The code works fine but I want to add an exception where a PIN would be invalid if it ends up in ascending order. For example if a PIN ended up being 1234, 3456, 4567 they would be invalid PINs.

```
public static String generatePin(int nmrPinDigits)
{
    String pin = new String();
    NUMBER_PIN_DIGITS = nmrPinDigits;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_PIN_DIGITS; i += 1) 
    {
        double rnd = Math.random();
        rnd *= 9;
        rnd += 1;
        byte rndByte = (byte)rnd;
        String rndStr = Byte.toString(rndByte);
        pin += rndStr;
    }
    return pin;
}
```

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: So where's the problem?

Comment: What kind of code have come up with so far?

Comment: Why don't you just generate random numbers from 0 to 9 instead of this convoluted piece of code with a type conversion etc?

Comment: Thanks AntonH, for the edit.

Comment: Do a test to subtract the first from the last, and that all 4 values are unique.  If the answer is 3, then you know they are in synchrous order.  Doesn't matter if it's 1234, or 5678.  It's like identifying a straight in poker.

Comment: Giovanni, I just made this using the notes from class, If i use int instead of double would that generate from 0-9?

Comment: @EricColgan : use `Random.nextInt(9) + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

Actually the question of the OP is probably more to know if the pin is a sequence. In which case:

```
char prev = pin.charAt(0);
for (char ch : pin.substring(1).toCharArray()) {
    if (chr - prev != 1) {
        // Not a sequence
        return false;
    }
    prev = chr;
}
// Is a sequence !
return true;
```

Same goes for descending order, just with `-1` as a test value.

Comment: also goes into if with pins such as `1569`, op just says "ascending order" though.

Comment: Arrays.sort method return void so your code will not compile as String constructor will not allow such statement

Comment: @niiraj874u: thanks for pointing that out. java is so verbose for that sort of simple things...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to compare each random digit generated in your loop to the previous one. If the difference is +1, discard the digit and generate another one.

Comment: Hi coder I thought the same thing, so i wanted to add into my loop something like pin != pin + 1; but I'm unsure of the syntax.

Comment: Yes that is true niiraj I never thought if that

Comment: If 1278 is acceptable, but 1234 is not, then the logic is a bit more complicated. For example, keep a single Boolean flag that tracks whether all previously generated digits are sequential or not. If after the forth digit is generated the flag is still true, regenerate the last digit until the flag becomes false. Avoid dealing with the string representation, though, as it adds complexity. Use this logic in your digit generation loop instead.

Comment: @coder : pins that start with a sequence (123*, 345* ...) will be slightly overrepresented in this case. (as `P(1231) == P(1231) + P(1234)*P(1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the method to detect ascending or descending string..

```
public static boolean checkForAscendingOrDescendingPart(String txt, int l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= txt.length() - l; ++i)
    {
        boolean success = true;
        char c = txt.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < l; ++j)
        {
            if (((char) c + j) != txt.charAt(i + j))
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success) return true;

        success = true;

        for (int j = 1; j < l; ++j)
        {
            if (((char) c - j) != txt.charAt(i + j))
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (success) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call this method before returning pin..and throw exception there..like..

```
checkForAscendingOrDescendingPart(pin, pin.length());
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need 2 loops